# How to override "duplicate entry warning" when run an append query (Access db, from c# asp.net)?

Tags: c#, ms-access, insert, duplicates, oledbcommand

I have a query in the access database that appends email addresses from one table to another. In the source table there may be many duplicated emails. In the target table the email field is unique. Before running the query,  there may already in the target table emails that are in the source table.

When running the query manually, I get a message about duplicates and I have to click on Yes to run the query anyway.
But when I try to run the query from the asp.net, c#, I get an exception and nothing is done.

How can I override the exception? I mean, how can I "tell" the system to assume I clicked on Yes after the warning?

Here is my code:
public static void RunQuery(string db, string command)
{
OleDbConnection conn = getConn(db);  //set the value for conn
try
{

```
            if (conn != null) conn.Close();
            conn.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = command;  // query name
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            
        }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error(e);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.Close();
            }

    }
```

---

Thanks

Comment: Modify the query (with a join to the source table) to append only non-existing records.

Answer (score 0):

It has never been clear when/how the error msg of duplicates will trigger.

I find that this (in most cases) will run the append query, and errors are ignored.

This:

```
        // run append query
        using (OleDbConnection conn = 
            new OleDbConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.AccessDB))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmdSQL =
                new OleDbCommand("AddToHotelss", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Now, the above runs this saved query in Access:

```
 INSERT INTO tblHotels2 ( FirstName, LastName, HotelName, EmailName )
 SELECT tblHotels.FirstName, tblHotels.LastName, tblHotels.HotelName, 
 tblHotels.EmailName
 FROM tblHotels
 WHERE (tblHotels.City = "Edmonton");
```

And I have a unique index on EmailName - and the above works.

So, give the "setting" of `CommandType = StoredProcedure`.

The above SHOULD work.

If it does not?

Then you have to consider introduction of the office.interop ACE data engine. (I don't think that's a good idea).

Or, if above idea does not work?

You have to modify your query to prevent duplicates in the first place..

The query then becomes this:

```
INSERT INTO tblHotels2 ( FirstName, LastName, HotelName, EmailName )
SELECT tblHotels.FirstName, tblHotels.LastName, tblHotels.HotelName, 
tblHotels.EmailName
FROM tblHotels
WHERE (tblHotels.City="Edmonton")
AND
(tblHotels.EmailName NOT IN (SELECT EmailName from tblHotels2.EmailName));
```

So, as suggested, you re-write the query to never allow duplicates.

I would however give the `commandText` setting (`StoredProcedure`) as per above - since in the past I had that work for me. (the duplicates message did not trigger, or stop the append).

Comment: Thanks. The 1st code didn't help. Changing the query with (tblHotels.EmailName NOT IN (SELECT EmailName from tblHotels2.EmailName)) made the access to work endlessly. I guess that it would do the work but may take hours because there are about 50000 records in the origin table and the "select" is done after each one.

What I ended up doping is to create a temporary table allowing the duplication of email and then ran a query that copied to the target only one occurrence of an email (with Group By)

Thanks

Comment: I assume there is a index on email? If not then that query will cause a full table scan). Access will mess up such queries, but without a index on email column, it will for sure run slow)